# How do I backup my complete iTunes library (to new a PC)?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, data-synchronization, windows

I am currently using XP on my laptop, which has the iTunes library. 
I use it to sync my iPod/iPad.

I am planning to buy a new laptop (Windows 7). How do I make the transition seamless to the new iTunes library switch ?
i.e. I should get all the Music/Movies/Apps/Photos,etc on my new Win 7 laptop seamlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a support document for this: [iTunes: How to move your music to a new computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4527). It also covers things like de-authorizing your old computer from the iTunes Store etc.

Comment: Is it only for Music...I also want to move other things...Videos, Apps, Books, Photos, etc